# Запятая? Тогда(,) при всех

Tags: пунктуация

> Что ему стоило тогда(,) при всех, задушить собственную жену?

Тогда — в то время.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая нужна. Здесь уточняющее обстоятельства времени.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая вряд ли нужна. Какое "при всех" обстоятельство времени?!

И вторая не нужна. Либо две, либо ни одной.

Comment: Запятая нужна. Обстоятельство времени тогда. Иначе смысл может измениться: Тогда = в том случае, при таких обстоятельствах.

Comment: Во как! Действительно...

Comment: "Что ему стоило в то время при всех задушить собственную жену?"

Нужна?

Comment: В этом случае нужна. Но в том случае я пояснил причину обособления.